# Use VBA to replace RegEx strings with hyperlinks in Word

Tags: regex, vba, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm trying to search through a word document and replace regex matches with a series of static hyperlinks.

For example, if I get a regex match for `"A-1"`, I want to replace the `"A-1"` string with a hyperlink with `Anchor = "A-1"` and `Address = "https://www.my_website.com/A-1"`. My RegEx matches could be `"A-1", "A-2", "A-3", etc`.

I'm familiar with RegEx but I'm very new to VBA. What I have so far:

```
Sub FindAndHyperlink()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = "([A][\-])([0-9])"

    Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
    For Each Match In Matches
        ActiveDocument.Range.Text = RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range.Text, (ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Match, Address:="https://www.my_website.com/" & Match))
    Next

End Sub
```

This doesn't compile because it's expecting a `)` after `ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add`.

I think the problem is that the `RegEx.Replace()` method is expecting `(String, String)` arguments rather than `(String, Hyperlink object)`, but I'm not sure the best way to get around that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think replace makes sense for what you're trying to do. I think it'd make more sense to clear the text at `Match.Range` and then instead add the hyperlink at the location of the `Match.Range`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 how would you do that? I'm thinking something like 
'For Each Match In Matches'
'Match.Text = ""'
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Match, Address:="https://www.my_website.com/" & Match'

Comment: Does `Matches` actually receive a range from `RegEx.Execute` of each match for that regex?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking I'd go for

Comment: You cannot do that with regex alone, the regex only works on plain text. Find the index in the document and try to add a hyperlink at that position.

Comment: You need to use Word's built-in Find functionality. It doesn't use RegEx, but it does have "wildcards" capability that's similar, just not as powerful. Should do the trick for this, though. Searching in the Internet should turn up a lot of examples. The Find will need to execute in a loop and each "hit" will need to process inserting the required hyperlink using the Word object model.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub FindAndHyperlink()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const HLnk As String = "https://www.my_website.com/"
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "A-[0-9]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Duplicate, Address:=HLnk & .Text, TextToDisplay:=.Text
    .Start = .Hyperlinks(1).Range.End
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it worked fine for me.

```
([a-z _:/.A-Z-1-9]+)
```

[image]

Notice the UPPERCASE and lowercase, plus the 1-9 (one through nine, inclusive), as well as the characters such as slash and period.